# why the result is different add thread by loop

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am the novice of multithreading, and I want to try to use the 2048*2048 height map texture to generate a set of vertices.

```
void HeightMap::CalculateVertices(Vector3 vertex_scale, Vector2 texture_scale, int start, int end, GLubyte* data) {
    for (unsigned int z = start; z < end; ++z) {
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            unsigned int offset = z * height + x;
            vertices[offset] = Vector3(x, data[offset], z) * vertex_scale;
            textureCoords[offset] = Vector2(x, z) * texture_scale;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to add thread to vector, if I add them one by one:

```
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&]
        {CalculateVertices(vertex_scale, texture_scale, 0, dataSize, data); }));
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&]
        {CalculateVertices(vertex_scale, texture_scale, dataSize, dataSize * 2, data); }));
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&]
        {CalculateVertices(vertex_scale, texture_scale, dataSize * 2, dataSize * 3, data); }));
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&]
        {CalculateVertices(vertex_scale, texture_scale, dataSize * 3, dataSize * 4, data); }));
```

Then everything run properly.

But if I use loop to add thread:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread([&]
            {CalculateVertices(vertex_scale, texture_scale, dataSize * i, dataSize * (i + 1), data); }));
    }
```

, the error occured, it shows the parameter "end" in the function "CalculateVertices" is 2560. Logically, the range should not exceed 2048.

Then I try to do some change, I just calculate the "start" and "end" not in the parameter list:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        int start = dataSize * i;
        int end = dataSize * (i + 1);
        threads.push_back(std::thread([&]
            {CalculateVertices(vertex_scale, texture_scale, dataSize * i, dataSize * (i + 1), data); }));
    }
```

, now the out of range problem is fixed, but the result still wrong, it seems only generate half of the vertices.

I am not familiar to multithreading, and this is my first attempt to use multithreading, I want to know the reason of the problem. According to my experience, I just change one-by-one code to loop, the logic should not be different.

Comment: you're capturing `i` by reference, you should capture by value if you want each thread to have its own value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret is your lazy auto-capture-by reference:

```
std::thread([&]{ /*...*/ })
```

This is almost always a *bad* idea. In this case, you are capturing `i` by reference, which means when the thread invokes the lambda, `i` might not even exist and will certainly not have the correct value.

At the very least, capture `i` by value. In fact, you can probably capture all this stuff by value in this case.

```
std::thread([=]{ /*...*/ })
```